# Showing Placeholders vs. Showing Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had an `Edit Information` form that showed `value`s and no placeholders.  I then added placeholders to the form with jQuery, but want the placeholders to only show if the value is empty.  Fields have values if the user has inputted this field's information at a previous time.

```
if ( $('[name="user_email"]').val() ) { $('[name="user_email"]').attr("placeholder", "Email").val(""); }
if ( $('[name="company"]').val() ) { $('[name="company"]').attr("placeholder", "Company Name *").val(""); }
if ( $('[name="password"]').val() ) { $('[name="password"]').attr("placeholder", "Password *").val(""); }
```

This is supposed to check if the field's value is empty with `if ( $('[name="user_email"]').val() )`, then if value is empty insert the placeholder.  Currently fields without a `value` are left blank but the fields with a `value` are given their placeholder.

If I put the placeholder in an else, like this

```
if ( $('[name="company"]').val() ){} else { $('[name="company"]').attr("placeholder", "Company Name *").val(""); }
```

it will print them correctly.  But that's long and messy, and the `if` check I have on the value's content obviously isn't working like I think it should.  How do I shorten this and get it to input values and placeholders correctly?

Comment: Actually the placeholders are working as expected. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to placeholders to only show if the field does not have a value.  These same fields are stored in the DB during Registration, and I only want the placeholders to show up if there's nothing in the database for the user.

Comment: Yes, that's what placeholders are for. They will be visible only when the input is empty.

Comment: I added an edit above. My logic is backwards from what it should be, need to know why my empty check isn't working.

Comment: You could simply define placeholder attribute on element with default value rest will be taken care by html itself. <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"> Try removing your code and adding placeholder attribute. And as Francesco mentioned below correct the check if you still want to control default behavior.

Comment: I cannot edit the html, it's form generated by a wordpress plugin. So I'm trying to do the placeholders with jQuery

Comment: $('[name="user_email"]').attr("placeholder","YOUR_VALUE"); OR if you want to correct the check  if ( ! $('[name="user_email"]').val() ) { IF EMPTY LOGIC}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use 3 statements below and remove the rest

```
$('[name="user_email"]').attr("placeholder", "Email");
$('[name="company"]').attr("placeholder", "Company Name *");//Company Name * will be shown as placeholder if field is empty
$('[name="password"]').attr("placeholder", "Password *"); //Same as above
```

Correct IF check would be

```
if(! $('[name="user_email"]').val() )
```

Comment: thanks, I picked up that .val("") on the fields at some point and it led me to having to do all this logic.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
if ( $('[name="user_email"]').val() )
```

you are checking if there is a value... NOT an empty value...
Your are coding like: if there is a value then add place-holder...

Comment: I added an edit above.  I know that's what I'm coding, but I think your answer is the same `if` check I'm doing, right? Maybe I can't see the difference bc there's no result to the `if` in the answer

Comment: There is no difference... I copied your code to show you that was wrong @VirgeAssault

Comment: oh ok. Well like I said, I knew it was wrong, was looking for how to make it right